# how to add image on plane using script unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my code to add a plane in unity but the problem is the octopus.jpg seems like not to work.

```
    GameObject my_plane;
    my_plane = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Plane);
    my_plane.transform.Rotate (-90, 0, 0);
    Texture my_img = (Texture)Resources.Load ("octopus.jpg");
    my_plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = my_img;
```

suggestion please or help . Thank you .
my octopus.jpg is in the resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to create a public field in your class :

public Texture my_img;

and just drag the texture that you want to use.

In case you are not running that code in a monobehaviour, you need to have your image inside a folder called "Resources" inside the "Assets" folder.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

Comment: but sir i need it cause i have lots of pictures to insert on my project.

Comment: Do you have your Resources folder created?